# Area specific login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

In my MVC 3 .net application I have two areas, one called Admin and one called Student. I use the built in membership system for user authentication, and it is unified between the two areas. The problem is, that I want to use area specific login pages, since the two areas diverse quite a bit in design (Student is targeted to mobile devices). As far as I know, I can only specify one login page for the application in Web.config, as so:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>`
```

In this case, how would I implement several login pages for the same membership system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only have 1 login URL specified for an ASP.NET application so you would need to do the following work-around:

In each Araa have a Login controller as well as a master Login controller in the root of the application.

In the Web.Config, make sure you have:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="/Admin/Account/LogOn">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="/Student/Account/LogOn">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

In your Web.Config configure the forms authentication to use the Login controller in the root application:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
```

Then in the root Login controller perform the following in the default action:

```
//
// GET: /LogOn
public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
{
    var area = returnUrl.TrimStart('/').Split('/').FirstOrDefault();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
        return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account", new { area });

    // TODO: Handle what happens if no area was accessed.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should read [this](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application) whitepaper. The solution to your problem is described in there.